# "peek" into eventfd internal counter value without changing

Tags: c, posix, file-descriptor

[Eventfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) maintains an uint64_t counter that is increased each time it is written onto and reset to zero (or decremented by 1 if using as EFD_SEMAPHORE) each time read from. Is it possible to peek into the value of an eventfd internal counter without changing it's value?

For example, you can retrieve it in a terminal using the 'cat' command as so, where 'eventfd-count' is the counter value:

```
$ cat /proc/<pid>/fdinfo/<efd>
pos:    0
flags:  02
mnt_id: 10
eventfd-count:               40
```

I can already read from `/proc/<pid>/fdinfo/<efd>` as a file and parse the response, but I am hoping for a more direct way of doing it on the actual eventfd fd resource. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No - looking at the entry in /proc is the only way you can look at the internal value without affecting it according to the [source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/eventfd.c) as of kernel version 4.20

Comment: @JSON There is ***no*** way to do that, except as you have discovered, to read /proc/<pid>/fdinfo/<efd>